# How to avoid the Jackrabbit DataStore "table or view does not exist" error?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jcr, jackrabbit

From time to time, our Jackrabbit (v2.6.1) system fails to automatically create the `DATASTORE_DATASTORE` table in an Oracle database, when setting up new environments. In this case, we see the following error in the application log file:

```
DbDataStore                              - Can not insert new record
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper.execute(ConnectionHelper.java:516)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper.reallyExec(ConnectionHelper.java:404)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper$3.call(ConnectionHelper.java:379)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper$3.call(ConnectionHelper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper$RetryManager.doTry(ConnectionHelper.java:557)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper.exec(ConnectionHelper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper.query(ConnectionHelper.java:359)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore.addRecord(DbDataStore.java:321)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.value.BLOBInDataStore.getInstance(BLOBInDataStore.java:121)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.value.InternalValue.getBLOBFileValue(InternalValue.java:626)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.value.InternalValue.create(InternalValue.java:381)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.value.InternalValueFactory.create(InternalValueFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.value.ValueFactoryImpl.createBinary(ValueFactoryImpl.java:77)
```

Our Jackrabbit configuration for the DataStore looks like this:

```
<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore">
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db:1521/SID" />
        <param name="user" value="foo" />
        <param name="password" value="foo" />
        <param name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024" />
        <param name="maxConnections" value="3" />
        <param name="copyWhenReading" value="true" />
        <param name="tablePrefix" value="" />
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="datastore_"/>
</DataStore>
```

This only seems to happen when we have multiple Jackrabbit instances on the same database instance, with each Jackrabbit instance in its own database schema/user. The issue only occurs with the `DATASTORE_DATASTORE` table - all other Jackrabbit tables work fine in this scenario.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Never heard of Jackrabbit, but my guess is either it tried and failed to set up the schema, in which case there should be a log file, or else it created it under a different user account and for some reason the account you are using to access it doesn't have privileges or isn't resolving the name. If you connect to the db, can you find it in dba_tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint for answering this question can be found in the [Jackrabbit DataStore FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore#FAQ):

> Q: When I use the database data store I get the message: 'Table or view does not exists'. A: Maybe the data store table already exists in another schema. When starting the repository, the database data store checks if the table already exists (using a database meta data call), and will create the table if not. If the table exists, but is in another schema, the table is not created, but accessing it may fail (if the other schema is not in the schema search path for this user).

It turns out that for the DataStore (all other tables use a different way of checking for the existence of the tables), Jackrabbit uses the database's metadata to check for the existence of the `DATASTORE_DATASTORE` table, and this is done in a way that does not take the user's database schema into account by default. That means that if there is another Jackrabbit schema on the same Oracle instance that already has a table called `DATASTORE_DATASTORE`, then Jackrabbit will think that the table is already there and will not try to create it in the user's schema.

Setting the recommended `tablePrefix` property in the `DataStore` configuration does NOT work:

```
<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore">
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db:1521/SID" />
        <param name="user" value="foo" />
        <param name="password" value="foo" />
        <param name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024" />
        <param name="maxConnections" value="3" />
        <param name="copyWhenReading" value="true" />
        <param name="tablePrefix" value="foo." />
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="datastore_"/>
</DataStore>
```

Doing this (with the period at the end of `tablePrefix`) will cause the table never to be found by Jackrabbit, and will result in even more errors, since Jackrabbit will not try to create the table every time the application is started.

There are two ways for fixing this permanently:

## Unique Table Name

This fix requires to manipulate either the `tablePrefix` or `schemaObjectPrefix` values so that the name of the table is unique in the whole database. For example for the first Jackrabbit instance use this:

```
<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore">
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db:1521/SID" />
        <param name="user" value="foo1" />
        <param name="password" value="foo1" />
        <param name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024" />
        <param name="maxConnections" value="3" />
        <param name="copyWhenReading" value="true" />
        <param name="tablePrefix" value="" />
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="FOO1_"/>
</DataStore>
```

This results in the table called `FOO1_DATASTORE` for this user. A second Jackrabbit instance in the same database could then use a configuration like this to ensure a unique table name:

```
<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore">
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db:1521/SID" />
        <param name="user" value="foo2" />
        <param name="password" value="foo2" />
        <param name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024" />
        <param name="maxConnections" value="3" />
        <param name="copyWhenReading" value="true" />
        <param name="tablePrefix" value="" />
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="foo2_"/>
</DataStore>
```

This results in this schema's table to be called `FOO2_DATASTORE`.

While this works, it's somewhat ugly and error-prone, since it requires changes to the configuration which are easily missed - and also is different from all of the other Jackrabbit tables, which work fine without this hack.

## Custom DbDataStore Class

The other solution is working around the issue in Jackrabbit's code. The original issue stems from the way Jackrabbit checks for the presence of the table in the database, through its `ConnectionHelper.tableExists` method (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core/2.6.1/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/util/db/ConnectionHelper.java?av=f#201), which checks for a flag called `checkTablesWithUserName`, which is set to `false` by default, resulting in a global check in the whole database (wrong!):

To get that flag set to `true`, a separate constructor needs to be called that allows to set the flag to `true`. To make this work, we need to create our own `UserCheckDbDataStore` class - it needs to be in the same package as the `ConnectionHelper` class to make use of the alternative constructor:

```
package org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper;

public class UserCheckDbDataStore extends DbDataStore {
    @Override
    protected ConnectionHelper createConnectionHelper(DataSource dataSrc) throws Exception {
        // Provide "true" as the second parameter to check in the user's schema
        return new ConnectionHelper(dataSrc, true, false);
    }
}
```

With this class in the classpath, the following Jackrabbit configuration works fine in the scenarios I have tested on both Oracle and MySQL:

```
<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.UserCheckDbDataStore">
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db:1521/SID" />
        <param name="user" value="foo" />
        <param name="password" value="foo" />
        <param name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024" />
        <param name="maxConnections" value="3" />
        <param name="copyWhenReading" value="true" />
        <param name="tablePrefix" value="" />
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="datastore_"/>
</DataStore>
```

Ideally, this bug/feature should be reported in the Jackrabbit bug tracker, but I'm not sure whether it would be fixed/merged since there have been similar requests with very little progress in the past.

Comment: by all means open a ticket and attach your patch; I can take care of it

Comment: Sorry, won't have time for reporting this today - and I'm going to be on vacation for the next two weeks. I'll create the ticket once I'm back...